# Finding the coordinate within a line if another coordinate and the distance are known.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

First of all, I'm really sorry if this question a bit messy. I've been solving this problem for 3 hours until I've got a headache, forgive me if I don't include my attempt in LaTeX equation.

The problem is here.

[image]

I have an equation (the equation is in blue line in the picture):

$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}x - \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}$$

The line is constructed from two points, i.e. $A=(-1,\, -\sqrt{3})$ and $B=(0, \,- \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3})$. Now. I have to find the coordinate $C(x,y)$ if the distance between $A$ and $C$ is $6$.

**Attempt**:

I had an idea to use distance formula. Now the problem is I still have two unknown variables. Thus, I drew a triangle, the slope is $y:x = \sqrt{3}:3$ (See my picture below).

[image]

This is the result using Wolfram Alpha:

[image]

I pick the first, since the second is positive. To find $y$ I just need to multiply it by $\sqrt{3}/3$.

[image]

However, when I plot using Geogebra, why isn't the point in the line like the picture shown below?

[image]

I've made sure that if I plug $x$ and $y$ into the distance formula, it's equal to $6$.

[image]

Where's the mistake? And do you have another simple way to solve this problem? I don't like this method. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to solve it by similar triangles. Draw a horizontal line $L$ through C. Drop a perpendicular through B to intersect L in a point D. Draw a horizontal line $L^\prime$ through A to intersect segment BD at point E. Do you see two similar right triangles? Can you use proportions to find the lengths of the hypotenuse of the larger triangle and use that to find your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the distance formula, realizing it is the equation for the hypotenuse of a triangle.  All you need is the slope of the line.  Every step made in the x direction is equivalent to $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ steps in the y direction. You know $6^2 = x^2 + y^2$ when you think about the problem as steps from a stationary point A. So, $36 = x^2 + \frac{x^2}{3} = \frac{4x^2}{3}$.  $x=3\sqrt{3}$.  $y=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}x = 3$.  So, these are the distances from point A.  You can check that the sum of their squares is 36. So point C is $(-1-3\sqrt{3}, -\sqrt{3}-3)$.